# Drawing animated lines in sequence (P5.js)

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to get a series of dots to be connected in sequence. I have the first two dots animating just fine. But after setting a condition which sets a boolean flag (`ready`) to true, the subsequent Dot objects are just instantiating the dots, but the animation isn't being triggered. Any thoughts on to where I'm going wrong here?

The code in the p5 editor https://editor.p5js.org/knectar/sketches/o-6N2rAn and here,

```
var dotPair;
var dotArray = [];
var tempX;
var tempY;
var angle = 0;
var ready = false; 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  noFill(0);
  stroke(50, 50, 200);
  strokeWeight(1);

  dotArray.push(new Dot());

}

function draw() {
  background(0);  

  for(let i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++){
    dotArray[i].showDotPair();
    dotArray[i].animateLine();
    dotArray[i].showLine();
  }

  if(ready){
    ready = false; 
    dotArray.push(new Dot());
  }

}

class Dot {

  constructor() {
    this.start = createVector(random(width), random(height));
    this.end = createVector(random(width), random(height));
    this.vertexArray = [];

  }

  showDotPair() {
    push();
    fill(200, 0, 0);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.start.x, this.start.y, 5);
    ellipse(this.end.x, this.end.y, 5);
    pop();
  }

  showLine() {
    beginShape();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.vertexArray.length; i++) {
      vertex(this.vertexArray[i].x, this.vertexArray[i].y);
    }
    endShape();    
  }

  animateLine() {

    tempX = map(angle, 0, 100, this.start.x, this.end.x, 1);
    tempY = map(angle, 0, 100, this.start.y, this.end.y, 1);

    this.vertexArray.push(createVector(tempX, tempY));

    if(tempX == this.end.x && tempY == this.end.y){
      ready = true; 
    }
    angle += 0.5;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation has to be done for the last doe only:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++){
    dotArray[i].showDotPair();
}
dotArray[dotArray.length-1].animateLine();
for(let i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++){
    dotArray[i].showLine();
}
```

`angle` has to be an attribute of `Dot`. Add input coordinate parameters to `Dot`, because the start of each `Dot` is the end of its parent:

```js
class Dot {

    constructor(x, y) {
        this.start = createVector(x, y);
        this.end = createVector(random(width), random(height));
        this.current = this.end;
        this.angle = 0.0;
    }

    // [...]
```

It is sufficient to draw a line from `start` to `end`, rather than drawing a shape (with tons of vertices). For the animation, the current point is stored in `current`.
See the example:

```js
var dotPair;
var dotArray = [];
var tempX;
var tempY;
var ready = false; 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  noFill(0);
  stroke(50, 50, 200);
  strokeWeight(1);

  dotArray.push(new Dot(random(width), random(height)));

}

function draw() {
    background(0);  

    for(let i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++){
        dotArray[i].showDotPair();
    }
    dotArray[dotArray.length-1].animateLine();
    for(let i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++){
        dotArray[i].showLine();
    }

    if(ready){
        ready = false; 
        let prev = dotArray[dotArray.length-1];
        dotArray.push(new Dot(prev.end.x, prev.end.y));
    }
}

class Dot {

    constructor(x, y) {
        this.start = createVector(x, y);
        this.end = createVector(random(width), random(height));
        this.current = this.end;
        this.angle = 0.0;
    }

    showDotPair() {
        push();
        fill(200, 0, 0);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.start.x, this.start.y, 5);
        ellipse(this.end.x, this.end.y, 5);
        pop();
    }

    showLine() {
        line(this.start.x, this.start.y, this.current.x, this.current.y)
    }

    animateLine() {
        tempX = map(this.angle, 0, 100, this.start.x, this.end.x, 1);
        tempY = map(this.angle, 0, 100, this.start.y, this.end.y, 1);

        this.current = createVector(tempX, tempY);

        if(tempX == this.end.x && tempY == this.end.y){
          ready = true; 
        }
        this.angle += 0.5;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: you rock, thank you so much. I need to parse a bit more, but this is exactly the result I'm looking for.